# C# Get home location of .csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, filepath, solution, csproj

I'm writing a class that will launch and manage a process for multiple other projects using .NET 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012. I've created a solution that contains two projects: the process executable and the process launcher/manager. This keeps the two closely associated and allows for multiple external projects to use the process manager by referencing the manager in their own respective solutions.

The project structure for process executable and manager looks like this:

`C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProcessAndManager\ProcessAndManager.sln`

`C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProcessAndManager\Process\Process.csproj`

`C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProcessAndManager\Manager\Manager.csproj`

Now I've switched to the other side of the coin, I've got an external project that would like to reference the manager in order to fire these processes using the manager.

The new solution and project are found, respectively

`C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProcessPlayground\ProcessPlayground.sln`

`C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProcessPlayground\ProcessPlayground\ProcessPlayground.csproj`

In ProcessPlayground.sln I've included a reference to Manager.csproj located as described above.

Now I go to use the manager from within the new, external project and I find that the manager does not have the correct path to the process .exe file. This is because in the manager class I use this line to set the location of the Process.exe

```
this.executableLocation = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Process.exe";
```

When done in the original solution this points to the project bin where Process.exe can be found:

`C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProcessAndManager\Process\bin\Debug`

But now in running from ProcessPlayground solution this value points to

`C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProcessPlayground\ProcessPlayground\bin\debug`

where Process.exe **CANNOT** be found.

So, I need a way to reference the source location of the Manager.csproj file from within (or its solution, I can use relative paths from there) rather than the current execution location. This will make deployment to any machine possible.

All help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance SO!

Comment: So if **Manager** must reference **Process** shouldn't **Process** just be in the same relative location to **Manager** each time?

Comment: did you try going back with  ..\\

Comment: It's source, yes. But since I'm using manager in many other solutions the returned value from Environment.CurrentDirectory points to the execution location of the other solutions, not Manager's source.

Comment: @loli Traversing up the tree to the common Visual Studio 2012\Projects folder isn't a complete solution. The location of the external solutions could be anywhere. I need the value to work without being relative to the external solution.

Comment: Slightly leftfield, but could you not create Process as a Nuget package? Then you could just pull it in to ProcessPlayground and reference the exe directly

Comment: I like that idea, but a bit overkill. My team and I worked out a solution. Since the process is a component that we will be installing it is going to live in Program Files. It will have a static location in deployment and so I can simply reference that static location. Not quite elegant, but successful.